# If $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$ are subgroup of $G$ then does the equality $\big\langle⟨ G_1\cup G_2⟩\cup G_3\big\rangle=⟨ G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3⟩$ holds?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

So it is a well knew result that any intersection of subgroup is a subgroup and even it is a well knew result that the union of subgroup is not generally a subgroup. However, if $\mathcal S(G)$ is the collection of subgroups of any group $G$ then for any subset $X$ of $G$ then the collection
$$
\mathcal G(X):=\{Y\in\mathcal S(G):X\subseteq Y\}
$$
is not empty so that its intersection $\langle X\rangle$ is a subgroup containing $X$ which is moreover the less subgroup containing it: thus if $\mathcal H$ is a collection of subgroups then we can say that
$$
\langle\mathcal H\rangle:=\Big\langle\bigcup\mathcal H\Big\rangle
$$
is the subgroup generated by $\mathcal H$.

Now I know that the equality
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}\begin{equation}\langle\mathcal H\rangle=\Big\{x_1\cdots x_n:x_i\in\bigcup\mathcal H\text{ for all }i=1,\dots, n\text{ with }n\in\omega\Big\}\end{equation}
$$
holds (**right?**) so that by this I asked if even the equality
$$
\tag{2}\label{2}\begin{equation}\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle=\big\langle\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle \cup G_3\big\rangle\end{equation}
$$
holds for any $G_1,G_2,G_3\in\mathcal S(G)$.

So first of all I observed that
$$
G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\subseteq\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle\cup G_3\subseteq\big\langle\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle\cup G_3\big\rangle
$$
holds so that I conclude that
$$
\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle\subseteq\big\langle\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle\cup G_3\big\rangle
$$
However, by \eqref{1} any element of $\big\langle\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle\cup G_3\big\rangle$ is a finite product of elements of $\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle$ and $G_3$ so that if by \eqref{1} any element of $\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle$ is a product of elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$ then by associativity and by \eqref{1} we conclude that
$$
\big\langle\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle\cup G_3\big\rangle\subseteq\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle
$$
Finally we conclude that the equality \eqref{2} holds.

So I ask if actually \eqref{2} holds because I do not know if really \eqref{1} holds since my textbook do not write it explicitly although, at least it seems, it proves it. Moreover if \eqref{2} holds then is it possibile to prove it using associativity of intersection? For sake of completeness [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rckX.png) a reference from my textbook - in Italian, sorry. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: You can also prove the opposite inclusion directly without needing to use (1): we have $G_1 \cup G_2 \subseteq \langle G_1 \cup G_2 \cup G_3 \rangle$, so $\langle G_1 \cup G_2 \rangle \subseteq \langle G_1 \cup G_2 \cup G_3\rangle$.  And also $G_3 \subseteq \langle G_1 \cup G_2 \cup G_3 \rangle$; therefore, $\langle G_1 \cup G_2 \rangle \cup G_3 \subseteq \langle G_1 \cup G_2 \cup G_3 \rangle$...

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh fine!!! Anyway could I ask if (1) actually holds?

Comment: Since $\cup\mathcal{H}$ is closed under inverses (that is, if $x\in\cup\mathcal{H}$ then $x^{-1}\in\cup\mathcal{H}$, the set of all finite products of elements of $\cup\mathcal{H}$ and the set of all finite products of elements of $\cup\mathcal{H}$ *and their inverses* is exactly the same thing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Perfect, all clear now.

Comment: As noted in a comment on my answer, you should either specify that your collection of subgroups is *nonempty*, or else you need to allow $n\in\omega$ and not merely in $\omega_+$, so that you can get the identity element (either as a nonempty product if $\cup\mathcal{H}\neq\varnothing$, or as the empty product in any case).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay, I understand. Only one question before to edit: if I put $\omega$ rather than $\omega_+$ then I have not to change $x_1\dots x_n$ with $x_0\dots x_n$ if I do not require $\cal H$ is not empty, right?

Comment: You should *not* change it to $x_0$ in any case. The whole point is that when $n=0$, the product $x_1\cdots x_0$ has no factors, and therefore equals the identity by definition. If you change it to $x_0$, then when $n=0$ you still have one factor. The whole point is to allow the empty product.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Perfect: so I edited the question changing $\omega_+$ with $\omega$ so that $\cal H$ could be even empty. Thanks for the indication! :-)

Comment: Let $G$ be a group and $X\subseteq G$. There are equivalent definition of subgroup of $G$ generated by $X$: $\langle X\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $X$$\iff$$\langle X\rangle =\bigcap_{i\in I} H_i$, where $\{H_i|i\in I\}$ is family of all subgroup of $G$ which contains $X$$\iff$$\langle X\rangle = \{a_1^{n_1}\cdots a_t^{n_t}\mid a_i\in X\text{ and }n_i\in \Bbb{Z}\}$. Definition of generator given in D&F is worse (or at least misleading IMO), [see post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4662724/861687). You may also check conversation between user lulu and I in comments.

Comment: @user264745 thanks for the comment and even for the upvoted whether you did the last I received. ;-)

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I forgot to mention main thing. Your proof is correct but it uses $G_1,G_2,G_3$ are subgroups of $G$. If subgroup conditions are removed, then $\langle \mathcal{H} \rangle$ is not correct. We can prove desired equality just with $G_1,G_2,G_3\subseteq G$ condition, as shown in answer by Arturo Magidin,. You don’t really have to explicitly say that you’re using associative law. Just prove generalised associative law once and for all.

Comment: @user264745 Yes, I understand. However, for sake of completeness, I have to point out that if $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$ are simply closed an analogous result holds as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4657648/736008) you can see by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both hold.

For any family $\{H_i\}_{i\in I}$ of subsets (not necessarily subgroups) of $G$, $\langle H_i\rangle$ is the subgroup $K$ that satisfies the following two conditions:

1. $H_i\subseteq K$ for each $i\in I$; and
2. if $M$ is any subgroup of $G$ such that $H_i\subseteq M$ for every $i\in I$, then $K\subseteq M$.

This is the "top-down description" of the subgroup generated. You use these properties in the second displayed equation after $(2)$.

We want to show that
$$\bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\bigr\rangle = \Bigl\langle \bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\bigr\rangle\cup G_3\Bigr\rangle.$$
(We don't even need to assume these are subgroups).

$\subseteq)$ Note that
$$\begin{align*}
G_1\cup G_2\subseteq \langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle &\subseteq \Bigl\langle \bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\bigr\rangle\cup G_3\Bigr\rangle\\
G_3\subseteq \langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle\cup G_3 &\subseteq \Bigl\langle \bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\bigr\rangle\cup G_3\Bigr\rangle
\end{align*}$$
Therefore,
$$(G_1\cup G_2)\cup G_3 = G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3 \subseteq
\Bigl\langle \bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\bigr\rangle \cup G_3\Bigr\rangle,$$
and since $\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup that contains $G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3$, we have
$$\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle \subseteq \Bigl\langle\bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\bigr\rangle\cup G_3\Bigr\rangle.$$

$\supseteq)$ Since $G_1\cup G_2\subseteq G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\subseteq \langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle$, we have
$\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle \subseteq \langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle$.

We also have $G_3\subseteq G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\subseteq \langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle$.

Since both $\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle$ and $G_3$ are contained in $\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\rangle$, their union is contained there as well, so
$$\langle G_1\cup G_2\rangle\cup G_3\subseteq \bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\bigr\rangle,$$
and therefore
$$\Bigl\langle  \bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\bigr\rangle \cup G_3\Bigr\rangle \subseteq \bigl\langle G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3\bigr\rangle,$$
as desired. $\Box$

More generally, for any family $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ of subsets of $G$, and any partition $\{I_j\}_{j\in J}$ of $I$ (so $\cup_{j\in J}I_j=I$), we have
$$\left\langle \bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\right\rangle = \left\langle \bigcup_{j\in J}\left\langle \cup_{i\in I_j}B_k\right\rangle\right\rangle.$$

As to whether your description of $(1)$ is accurate, note that in general if $S$ is a subset of $G$, $\langle S\rangle$ is the collection of all finite products of elements of $S$ *and their inverses*. But if $S$ is closed under inverses, that is, if $S$ satisfies the condition
$$\text{if }s\in S,\text{ then }s^{-1}\in S,$$
then this is exactly the same thing as the collection of all finite products of elements of $S$. (Note the empty product is a finite product and gives the identity element). Since your $\cup\mathcal{H}$ is a union of subgroups, it is certainly closed under inverses; and you can ignore the empty product since the set already contains $e$; so your description of $\langle \cup\mathcal{H}\rangle$ is accurate if the family of subgroups is nonempty.

Comment: Oh, very nice answer! Thanks really for it and so for your assistance. :-)

Comment: In the given version of (1), it is required for $n \in \omega_+$, so in the generalization, you might also want to require that $S$ is nonempty (which of course it is in the case of a nonempty union of subgroups).  (Then of course, if you allow the empty product and say that that product evaluates to the identity, you can also allow $\langle \emptyset \rangle = \{ e \}$ to be a special case.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler: I say "finite products", rather than use $\omega_+$, but I'll note it for the OPs set.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for the observation!!! :-)