# Prove or disprove the equality $\biggl\langle\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y\biggl\rangle = \bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y}\langle Y\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

A [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) is a pair given $(X,\bot)$ given by a set $X$ and a function from $X\times X$ to $X$ so that we say that $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$ is closed under $\bot$ if the inclusion
$$
\bot[Y\times Y]\subseteq Y
$$
holds.

So we immediately observe that if $\mathcal U$ is a collection of closed set of $X$ under $\bot$ with not empty intersection then even its intersection $\bigcap\mathcal U$ is closed under $\bot$ since if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are in $\bigcap U$ then they are even in $U$ for any $U\in\mathcal U$ so that $u_1\bot u_2$ is in $U$ and thus trivially in $\bigcap U$.

Now $X$ is trivially closed with respect $\bot$ so that the collection
$$
\mathcal S(\bot):=\{U\in\mathcal P(X):\bot[U\times U]\subseteq U\}
$$
is not empty and thus for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$ the collection
$$
\mathcal U_Y:=\{U\in\mathcal S(\bot):Y\subseteq U\}
$$
is not empty and additionally if $Y$ is not empty and if any $U\in\mathcal U_Y$ contains $Y$ then their intersection $\langle Y\rangle$ is not empty so that **it is the smallest closed set of $X$ under $\bot$ containing $Y$**: in fact, what proved above implies that $\langle Y\rangle$ is closed and moreover if $U\in\mathcal P(X)$ is closed and contains $Y$ then $U$ is in $\mathcal U_Y$ so that the inclusion
$$
\langle Y\rangle\subseteq U
$$
holds.

First of all we observe that the operator
$$
\langle\quad\rangle:\mathcal P(X)\ni Y\longrightarrow\langle Y\rangle\in\mathcal P(X)
$$
is monotonous with respect the inclusion: in fact, if $U,V\in\mathcal P(X)$ are such that
$$
U\subseteq V
$$
then the inclusion
$$
U\subseteq V\subseteq\langle V\rangle
$$
holds so that what above showed implies that
$$
\langle U\rangle\subseteq\langle V\rangle
$$
Moreover if $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$ is closed then it is in $\mathcal U_Y$ so that the inclusion
$$
\langle Y\rangle\subseteq Y
$$
holds and thus if trivially even the inclusion
$$
Y\subseteq\langle Y\rangle
$$
holds then we finally conclude that
$$
Y=\langle Y\rangle
$$
which additionally implies that $\langle\quad\rangle$ is idempotent.

Now let be $\mathfrak V$ a partition of $\mathcal Y\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ so that let's we prove the equality
$$
\tag{0}\label{0}\Biggl\langle\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y} Y\Biggl\rangle
=
\Biggl\langle\bigcup_{\mathcal V\in\mathfrak V}\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V} V\biggl\rangle\Biggl\rangle
$$
holds.

> So if $\mathfrak V$ partition $\mathcal Y$ then the equality
> $$
> \bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y
> =
> \bigcup_{\mathcal V\in\mathfrak V}\Biggl(\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V\Biggl)
> $$
> holds and so for any $V\in\mathfrak V$ the inclusion
> $$
> \bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V\subseteq\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y
> \subseteq
> \Biggl\langle\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y\Biggl\rangle
> $$
> holds; but we know that $\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V\biggl\rangle$ is the smallest closed set containing $\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}$ so that the last inclusion implies that
> $$
> \bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}\biggl\rangle\subseteq
> \Biggl\langle\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y}\Biggl\rangle
> $$
> and thus reapplying the argument finally we conclude that
> $$
> \tag{1}\label{1}\Biggl\langle\bigcup_{\mathcal V\in\mathfrak V}\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V\biggl\rangle\Biggl\rangle
> \subseteq
> \Biggl\langle\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y\Biggl\rangle
> $$
> However for any $Y\in\mathcal Y$ there exists $\mathcal V_Y\in\mathfrak V$ such that
> $$
> Y\subseteq\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V_Y\in\mathcal V_Y}V_Y\biggl\rangle
> $$
> so that taking the union over $\mathcal Y$ we conclude that
> $$
> \bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y
> \subseteq
> \bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y}\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V_Y\in\mathcal V_Y}V_Y\biggl\rangle
> \subseteq
> \bigcup_{\mathcal V\in\mathfrak V}\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V\biggl\rangle\Biggl\rangle
> \subseteq
> \Biggl\langle\bigcup_{\mathcal V\in\mathfrak V}\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V\biggl\rangle\Biggl\rangle\Biggl\rangle
> $$
> which implies that
> $$
> \tag{2}\label{2}\Biggl\langle\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y\Biggl\rangle
> \subseteq
> \Biggl\langle\bigcup_{\mathcal V\in\mathfrak V}\biggl\langle\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V\biggl\rangle\Biggl\rangle
> $$
> So by \eqref{1} and by \eqref{2} we conclude that the equality \eqref{0} holds.

Now I am quite sure what I have done above is quite correct but I deliberated to do it because e.g. I know that \eqref{0} is surely corrected for subgroup as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4655770/736008) the professor Magidin said lefting for exercise the proof: so surely I ask if I well proved all things I did until now. However now I asked to me if additionally the equality

$$
\tag{3}\label{3}
\biggl\langle\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y\biggl\rangle
=
\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y}\langle Y\rangle
$$
holds.

> In fact, I observed that for any $Y\in\mathcal Y$ the inclusion
> $$
> \bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y} Y
> \subseteq
> Y
> \subseteq
> \langle Y\rangle
> $$
> holds so that even the inclusion
> $$
> \bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y} Y
> \subseteq
> \bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y}\langle Y\rangle
> $$
> but by above proved we know that $\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y}\langle Y\rangle$ is closed so that the inclusion
> $$
> \tag{4}\label{4}
> \biggl\langle\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y}Y\biggl\rangle
> \subseteq
> \bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal Y}\langle Y\rangle
> $$
> holds.

So I was not able to prove the reverse of \eqref{4} so that I ask if it to prove it or disprove it with a counterexample. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: “Now let be $$ a partition of $$” – What is $$ in this case? Do you mean $Y$?

Comment: @LukasJuhrich $\mathcal Y$ is any set of indices.

Comment: This makes no sense: Then an element $Y∈\mathcal Y$ is an index, and if you write $\bigcup_{Y\in \mathcal Y} Y$ I can't parse this: I don't know how to take unions of indices.

Comment: @LukasJuhrich Sorry, you are right. $\mathcal Y$ is any set of subsets of $X.$

Comment: @LukasJuhrich I confirm: $\cal Y$ is just a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of $(1),(2),(0)$ is ok.

Now, in $X=\{0,1\}$ with $\forall x,y\in X\quad x\bot y=0,$ define
$Y_k=\{k\}$ ($\forall k\in X$). Then,
$$\langle Y_0\cap Y_1\rangle=\langle\varnothing\rangle=\varnothing,$$
whereas
$$\langle Y_0\rangle\cap\langle Y_1\rangle=\{0\}\cap X=\{0\}.$$

Comment: Perfect: thanks for the simple counterexample. Only one last question before to approve the answer: did I prove correctly (1)?

Comment: Perfect: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!!! :-)